# Prove that a sequence $a_n$ converges iff $a_n^3$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I want to prove that

> $A\ sequence\ a_n\ converges\ \longleftrightarrow\ a_n^3\ converges$

If $a_n$ converges, then by arithmetics, $a_n^3$ converges.

Now let $a_n^3$ converge to a real $L$.

Take the function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$, which is well defined for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then we know that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, f(a_n^3) = \sqrt[3]{a_n^3} = a_n$.

$f$ is continuous, so by taking the limit:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n^3) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^3) = f(L) = \sqrt[3]{L}$.

Does this proof hold?
And also, I was wondering how can you prove it from definition, using $\epsilon$ notation?

Thanks!

Comment: The proof is okay. Conversion to $\epsilon, N$ arguments ($\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb N : \forall n \ge N |a_n-L| < \epsilon$) will be very tiresome. The choice of $N$ can be derived from the derivative of $\sqrt[3]x$ and the convergence rate of $a_n^3$.